# Linq to objects filtering IN and not in

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Looking for an example where I can filter my collection based on some filtering criteria.

I have been looking for some example where given a list /array i can filter a collection.

In the example below in my find method I am trying to filter based on 2 values ,looking for something like an "IN" function any suggestions?

```
        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                //Print all customres that belong to below deparments and match on surname
                var criteria=new Criteria
                                 {
                                     Departments = new List<string> {"BusinessAnalyst", "Account"},
                                     Surname = "Bloggs"
                                 };

                List<Customer> customers = Repository.Find(criteria);

                customers.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Surname: {0} Department :{1}", x.Surname,x.Department)));

                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        public class Repository
        {
           public static List<Customer>GetCustomers()
            {
                return  new List<Customer>
                                    {
                                        new Customer { Name = "Jon",Surname="Smith",Department = DepartmentType.Managers},
                                        new Customer{Name = "Bill",Surname = "Gates",Department = DepartmentType.Managers},
                                        new Customer { Name = "Mary",Surname = "Bug",Department = DepartmentType.Developers},
                                        new Customer { Name = "Mark",Surname="Boo",Department = DepartmentType.Account},
                                        new Customer{Name = "Ron",Surname = "Scott",Department = DepartmentType.Managers},
                                        new Customer { Name = "Jonny",Surname = "Dip",Department = DepartmentType.Developers},
                                        new Customer { Name = "Mary",Surname = "Bloggs",Department = DepartmentType.BusinessAnalyst},

                                        new Customer { Name = "Mary",Surname = "Bug",Department = DepartmentType.Account},
                                        new Customer { Name = "Jonny",Surname = "Dip",Department = DepartmentType.Account},
                                        new Customer { Name = "Mary",Surname = "Bloggs",Department = DepartmentType.Managers}
                                    };
            }

           public static List<Customer> Find(Criteria criteria)
           {
               List<Customer>customers=Repository.GetCustomers();

               //Filter on departments
               //ERROR HERE AS I cannot do this "IN" would be fantastic.
               customers = customers.Contains(criteria.Departments);

               //now filter on name
               customers = customers.Where(x => x.Surname == criteria.Surname).ToList();


               return customers;
           }
        }

        public enum DepartmentType
        {
            Account,
            Managers,
            Developers,
            BusinessAnalyst
        }
        public class Customer
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public DepartmentType Department { get; set; }

        }
        public class Criteria
        {
            public Criteria()
            {
                Departments=new List<string>();
            }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public List<string> Departments { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Considering you use an Enum for the Department (DepartmentType), shouldn't your Criteria use the same instead of a string?

Comment: If there are many entries in `criteria.Departments` collections you should make it a `HashSet<T>` to get fast `Contains`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static List<Customer> Find(Criteria criteria)
{
    List<Customer> customers = Repository.GetCustomers();

    var customers2 = customers.Where(x => criteria.Departments.Contains(x.Department.ToString()));

    var customers3 = customers2.Where(x => x.Surname == criteria.Surname);

    return customers3.ToList();
}
```

But considering you use an `enum` for the `Department` (`DepartmentType`), shouldn't your `Criteria` class use the same instead of a `string`?

If you define the `criteria.Departments` as `List<DepartmentType>` then you can write

```
public static List<Customer> Find(Criteria criteria)
{
    List<Customer> customers = Repository.GetCustomers();

    var customers2 = customers.Where(x => criteria.Departments.Contains(x.Department));

    var customers3 = customers2.Where(x => x.Surname == criteria.Surname);

    return customers3.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .Silly me I should have realised when I put this noddy example together .

Answer (score 2):

Contains returns a bool defining whether a specified object is contained in a collection. Based on your example, you will need to use `Where` to filter the customers, then use `Contains` on the departments:

```
 customers = customers.Where(c => criteria.Departments.Contains(c.Department));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
Customers.Where(c => criteria.Departments.Contains(c.Department.ToString()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I get "Cannot be inferred from usage".Is it because Department is an ENUM

Comment: Since `criteria.Departments` is a list of `string`s, you need to check whether it contains a `string` by calling `ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

i think you want something like this..

```
customers = customers.Where(c => criteria.Departments.Contains(c.Department));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but the following:

```
    List<Customer> FilteredCustomers = (from c in customers where Criteria.Departments.Contains(c.deparment) && c.surname == Criteria.Surname select c).ToList();
```

Would equate to something like this in SQL:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM Customers
    WHERE Department IN (
    List of departments
    ) 
    AND Surname = surname
```

I haven't tested this but I think it should work and bring back what you want.